# Moving rigidbody2d towards mouse click using AddForce

Tags: unity, physics

I cant get my rigidbody2d game object to move to where i click the mouse. The first click works. The object travels to the mouse click and stops. But the second time (or the third time) i click the object travels in som direction but its not quite correct and it never reaches the target! What am i not getting right?

```
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
             var mouseClick = Input.mousePosition;
             mouseClick.z = player.transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
             target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (mouseClick);
             rotateToTarget = false;
             travelToTarget = true;
             print ("NEW TARGET: " + target);
             Debug.DrawLine (Camera.main.transform.position, target, Color.red, 10f);
      }

      if (rotateToTarget == false && travelToTarget == true) {

             var distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance (player.transform.position, target);


             if (distanceToTarget > 2) {

                print ("Distance: " + distanceToTarget);

                target.z = 0;

            player.rigidbody2D.AddForce (target * travelSpeed);

             } else {

                travelToTarget = false;
                print ("travelling COMPLETE");
             }        
      }
```

Comment: It looks ok at first glance. The debugDrawLine looks correct?
What is the output on the second click?

Comment: The output is always correct. But the movement is not. :P

Comment: I notice you set target.z to 0 after drawing the debugLine, perhaps that could cause something. I suggest you print out the values and go step by step with pen and paper to make sure all the variables are what you'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the error:

```
player.rigidbody2D.AddForce (target * travelSpeed);
```

You are ignoring the players current position, which is why it only works once because the initial position is (0,0,0).

Use `(target - player.transform.position) * travelSpeed` instead.